# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3+6n^2}{2n^2+5n+6}$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

I was copying my teacher slides and I noticed something weird. If you look at Key Flex answer, it shows why I used zero initially(Look at edit logs). I have noticed the problem in my question, so I will post another question in a new post explaining the problem. So the question is this:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^3+6n^2}{2n^2+5n+6} \tag{1}$$

Steps on how teacher solved it:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^3+6n^2}{2n^2+5n+6} \tag{2}$$

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^2(n+6)}{n^2\left(2+\dfrac{5}{n}+\dfrac{6}{n^2}\right)}\tag{3}$$

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\infty+6}{2+\dfrac{5}{\infty}+\dfrac{6}{\infty^2}} =\infty \tag{4}$$

Shouldn't it be: 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\infty+6}{2+\dfrac{5}{\infty}+\dfrac{6}{\infty^2}} =\dfrac{6}{2}=3 \tag{5}$$

Comment: There is no $x$ in your equation. Should we instead assume you're taking the limit in terms of $n$? If so, how did you get from line 2 to line 3?

Comment: Sorry about that @Kaynex, it has been edited. Wait a line was deleted. Lemme fix that

Comment: "I know as limn→∞ it will equal to 0"  You know the limit of *what* will equal zero?

Comment: Where did those zeros come from?

Comment: You seem to be “plugging in” 0 for $n.$ Why are you doing that? $n$ is approaching $\infty,$ not $0.$ Also even if that step were correct $5/0$ is by no means zero.

Comment: Replacing $n$ with $0$ doesn't make any sense.  I dont see why you did than. And $\frac 50\ne 0$.  And $\lim_{n\to \infty} n+ 6\ne 6$.  Neither what you nor what your teacher is doing makes sense.

Comment: Your teacher’s solution would make a heuristic sort of sense if you replaced all the zeroes by infinities.

Comment: All those $0$'s in equation (4) should be $\infty$'s (and you can drop the "$\lim_{n\to\infty}$).

Comment: @BarryCipra we do we drop the limit notation?

Comment: You can also neglect lower degree terms against greater ones, only if the limit is tending towards $\infty$ ie. $6n^2$ in $N^{r}$ and $5n+6$ in $D^{r}$

Comment: @narusin, when you replace all the $n$'s with $\infty$'s, you have, in effect, taken the limit, so there's no need to take it again. (The expression in equation (4) no longer contains any $n$'s.) You should also now be able to see that $\infty+6=\infty$, not $6$, in equation (5). Please note, though, that writing algebraic expressions with the infinity symbol is just an informal way of expressing things, and really should be avoided when you're first learning to work with limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When taking infinite limits of "polynomial-over-polynomial" expressions, the polynomial with the bigger degree *wins*. (In the case of a tie, the coefficients give the answer.)

In the simplest case, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^p}{n^q} \quad=\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}\begin{cases}
n^{p-q} & \text{if}\;p>q \\[4pt]
1 & \text{if}\;p=q \\
\dfrac{1}{n^{q-p}} & \text{if}\;p<q
\end{cases}
\quad=\quad
\begin{cases}
\infty \\[6pt]
1 \\[6pt]
0
\end{cases}$$
which reflects the fundamental limiting nature of infinity. (The (positive) power of larger and larger numbers gets larger and larger; and the *reciprocal* of the (positive) power of larger and larger numbers gets smaller and smaller. (And, of course, $1$ is a constant, so it stays ... um ... *constant*.)

More generally, we use the algebraic trick your employed by your teacher (and other answers here). I'll present it a little differently.
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_pn^p+a_{p-1}n^{p-1} + \cdots + a_0}{b_qn^q+b_{q-1}n^{q-1}+\cdots + b_0} &=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \frac{n^p\left(a_p + \dfrac{a_{p-1}}{n}+\cdots+\dfrac{a_0}{n^{p}}\right)}{n^q\left(b_q + \dfrac{b_{q-1}}{n}+\cdots+\dfrac{b_0}{n^q}\right)}\right) \\[6pt]
&=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^p}{n^q}\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_p + \dfrac{a_{p-1}}{n}+\cdots+\dfrac{a_0}{n^{p}}}{b_q + \dfrac{b_{q-1}}{n}+\cdots+\dfrac{b_0}{n^q}}\right) \\[6pt]
&=
\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^p}{n^q}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{a_p + 0+\cdots+0}{b_q + 0+\cdots+0}\right) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{a_p}{b_q}\;\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^p}{n^q} \\[4pt]
&=\begin{cases}
\infty & \text{if}\;p > q \\[4pt]
a_p/b_q & \text{if}\;p=q \\[4pt]
0 &\text{if}\; p < q
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

That is, if the numerator's degree is higher, the limit shoots up to infinity; if the denominator's degree is higher, the limit is dragged down to zero. When the degrees match, the polynomials effectively cancel, leaving only their leading coefficients.

---

In the problem at hand, $n^3 + 6 n^2$ has higher degree than $2n^2+5n+6$, so the limit as $n$ approaches infinity should itself be infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Though tempting at first, one should **not** replace values of the variable inside the limit since this can lead to incorrect results. You can, alternatively, manipulate the expression algebraically:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^3+6n^2}{2n^2+5n+6} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^3(1+\frac{6}{n})}{n^3(\frac{2}{n}+\frac{5}{n^2}+\frac{6}{n^3})} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1+\frac{6}{n}}{\frac{2}{n}+\frac{5}{n^2}+\frac{6}{n^3}}
$$

I think you can take it from here: the denominator converges to $0$, and the numerator to $1$, thus, the quotient diverges to infinity.

Comment: Yeah, I reordered the sentenced and missed it. Thanks!

Comment: How does $\dfrac{1}{0}=\infty$. Also, why did you take out $n^3$ instead of $n^2$?

Comment: @narusin what definition of limit are you using? Again, I would not abuse notation that way unless you feel really comfortable with these sort of things.

Comment: @GuidoA. Can you explain what do you mean by what definition are we using?

Comment: Yes, of course. When you write $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$ for some sequence of numbers $a_1,a_2 \dots$, what do you mean by that? Objects in mathematics have precise meaning.

Comment: @GuidoA. can we talk about this in a chat room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79773/discussion-between-naru-sin-and-guido-a).

Answer (score 1):

Your instructor is correct.

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n+6}{2+\dfrac{5}{n}+\dfrac{6}{n^2}} =\dfrac{\infty+6}{2+\dfrac{5}{\infty}+\dfrac{6}{\infty^2}}=\dfrac{\infty}{2}=\infty $$

Note that $\infty +6 =\infty $ and $ \frac {\infty}{2}=\infty$

Comment: My teacher used 0 instead of $\infty$

Comment: @narusin It should have been $\infty$ as it is shown in step $(4)$

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^3+6n^2}{2n^2+5n+6} > \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n^3+6n^2}{6n^2} \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{6}n + 1,$$

which diverges to infinity.